# Sharepoint URL field control in custom application pages

Tags: sharepoint, url, controls, field

We want Sharepoint URL field control in custom application pages but some how it is not shown in pages.
We are using control below html format

```
<SharePoint:UrlField FieldName="txttest1" ControlMode="New" CssClass="txttest1" runat="server"/>
```

let me know how we can do that. so that it can look like/display sharepoint control.

Comment: What does the URL to your page look like? I'm not sure if UrlField will work without context to a list item and unless this page acts like a list item form.

Comment: Hi Rich, You are right without list context field it's not working. Thanks!